# Is it legal for a package to depend on a development package?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, packaging

I have a package that needs dpkg-dev to be installed. So I've added it as a dependency and it works as expected, but now I'm wondering whether it is legal practice according to the Debian packaging rules.

Here is how the result looks like:

```
Package: snapcmakemodules
Section: devel
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, dpkg-dev
Description: Common Snap C++ CMake modules
 This package contains common CMake modules to support Snap C++ projects.
```

My package includes a perl script which requires perl files found in the `dpkg-dev`.

Comment: The section is called `devel`, it doesn't mean that the package is under development. It is a package needed for development purposes.

Comment: @mook765 Yes, the `snapcmakemodules` is used to handle all sorts of things in our modules. So it's a development package. Are you saying that it makes sense for a `devel` package to depend on another `devel` package?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, absolutely.

Comment: @mook765 Could you merge comments as answer. It does solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages in the section `devel` are packages needed for development purpuses.

It is absolutely fine when another package (even if itself is in the `devel`-section) depends on a package in the `devel`-section if you need the functionality of this package.